# adding an icon on WooCommerce product gallery and having flex slider arrows

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

i am running a woo shop and want to add gallery arrows and an icon to my PDPs product gallery.

each of those hook work separately, but if I add them together, the arrows are not being called. is there a sort of prioritizing issue? I don't think it is a css issue.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
function woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails()
{
echo '<img class="imgB1" src="https://placehold.it/100" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.8%;
    right: 15%;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border: 5px solid red;
">';
}

// Update WooCommerce Flexslider options

add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', 'ud_update_woo_flexslider_options' );

function ud_update_woo_flexslider_options( $options ) {
    
    echo '<style type="text/css">
         
    ul.flex-direction-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        z-index: 99999;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
    }

    li.flex-nav-prev {float: left;}
    li.flex-nav-next {float: right;}
    a.flex-next {visibility:hidden;}
    a.flex-prev {visibility:hidden;}
    a.flex-next::after {
        visibility:visible;content: "\f105";
        font-family: FontAwesome;margin-right: 10px;font-size: 70px;    
    }
    a.flex-prev::before {
        visibility:visible;
        content: "\f104";
        font-family: FontAwesome;    margin-left: 10px;font-size: 70px;
    }
         
         </style>';

    $options['directionNav'] = true;
    $options['animation'] = "slide";
    $options['animationLoop'] = true;
    
    return $options;
}
```

any idea?

thanks!

Comment: I think the hook woocommerce_product_thumbnails overrules a lot of other stuff. also the image gallery is affected by this

Comment: If you got the solution, why don't you answer here, please?

Comment: hi. not a real solution, but a workaround. I've added it to title.php